# What does the following piece of C code do

Tags: c

```
int (*ptr)[10];
```

I know what `int *ptr[10];` its a 10 member array where each element is a pointer to an integer.

But what does the above piece code create ?

Comment: People there're zillion dupes for this, marking this dupe is more prudent than answering for rep.

Comment: BTW, parentheses modify precedence. Read the declarator precedence rules of C. Obviously, if `int *ptr[10]` is an array of pointers, then `int (*ptr)[10]` must be a pointer to array.

Comment: @legends2k Agreed, also please stop upvoting.

Comment: @H2CO3: Exactly, just because someone sees this for the first time, they upvote it, instead of knowing about (such old concepts) from searching or reading related material, thereby increasing the fake-value of dupes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *ptr[10]
```

is an array of 10 `int` pointers,

`int (*ptr)[10]`

is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s

Comment: ... and I think what matters is the result of ptr++ in each case.

Comment: re-read my question. You and I said the same thing about int *ptr[10] :|

Comment: -1 There's no need for answering this duplicate question yet another time.

Comment: @GreenAsJade : yes it does. `*(ptr++)`, `(*++p)` ... to add to it

Answer (score 1):

Cdecl (http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*p%29[10] ) says:

```
declare p as pointer to array 10 of int
```

That is: ptr is a pointer to an array, which is rarely useful. See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html